# Validate required properties using javascript submit

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I submited a form using javascript (must check pre-condition first), and I noticed that I'm not notified about unfilled required properties:

```
function offerContract() // the function called when deployContractBtn is clicked
    {
        document.getElementById("CreateContractDialogMessage").innerHTML = "";
        ErrorMsg = checkErrors();

            if (ErrorMsg != "")
            {
                $('#CreateContractDialogTitle').text("Error"); //show error headline
                document.getElementById("CreateContractDialogMessage").innerHTML = ErrorMsg;
                document.getElementById("closeButton").style.display = "block";
                $('#dialogOfferContract').modal('show');
                return;
            }

        $("#deployContractBtn").submit() //type = button and not submit

    }


    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeployContract", "CreateContract", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "DeployContractForm" }))
    {
       .....The rest of the form....    
       <input id="deployContractBtn" onclick="offerContract()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Sign&Deploy Contract" disabled />

    }
```

How to notify about the unfilled requierd properties using javascript as the classic submit does? Is it possible to mark them, so the user will know where he needs to insert values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage default browser UI, you can just mark the field as `required`. By default, the form will now allow a user to submit it until the requirements are met.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input placeholder="this field is required" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, If you want a little more customization you can use JavaScript to do what you want.

```js
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    // TODO: Submit form code here
    console.log('Form submitted');
    return;
  } else {
    const nameField = document.getElementById('nameField');
    if (!nameField.checkValidity()) {
      alert('The Name Field is a required field. Please provude a valid value');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input placeholder="this field is required" id="nameField" required />
</form>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: If you don't give the control a name, it won't be submitted anyway. ;-)

Comment: How to grab the values in the form on the backend wasn't part of the question. The question was how to show the user which fields need to be filled out if they are required and still blank.